# Error while loading items: no deployed process definition found

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

In the dashlet "My tasks" there are two items: "Current tasks" and "Completed tasks".

When I click on the "Completed tasks" I see the following error on a red background:

> Error while loading items

When this error occurs in the logs I see the following.

catalina.out:

```
...
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiObjectNotFoundException: no deployed process definition found with id 'publishWhitepaper:1:1115'
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentManager.findDeployedProcessDefinitionById(DeploymentManager.java:75)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.GetDeploymentProcessDefinitionCmd.execute(GetDeploymentProcessDefinitionCmd.java:39)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.GetDeploymentProcessDefinitionCmd.execute(GetDeploymentProcessDefinitionCmd.java:26)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getDeployedProcessDefinition(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:138)
        at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiUtil.getDeployedProcessDefinition(ActivitiUtil.java:133)
        at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiTypeConverter.getTaskDefinition(ActivitiTypeConverter.java:223)
        at org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.LazyActivitiWorkflowTask.<init>(LazyActivitiWorkflowTask.java:93)
        at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiWorkflowEngine.getAssignedTasks(ActivitiWorkflowEngine.java:1543)
        ... 92 more
```

Before that I installed and watched [some examples](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/tree/master/workflow) of business processes, <s>but then deleted them (and via workflow console).</s> - *most likely, I didn't do it correctly...*

I can't understand why this error appear?..

> no deployed process definition found with id
>   'publishWhitepaper:1:1115'

Maybe somewhere something is cached?

Comment: it sounds like you are giving advice to yourself... :-)

Comment: I think you may have removed the process definition file.right?

Comment: After adding all the files which are required for Custom workflow. and you have started your workflow 
and removed the custom workflow files so for that reason It is possible.

Comment: Even we had similar issues and you need to delete the referenced workflows(publishWhitepaper) using activiti-admin console.                   Note : Activiti admin console is part of Alfresco Enterprise feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Axel Faust](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/16045) gave an exhaustive answer:

[Is there enough functionality of the workflow admin console?](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/is-there-enough-functionality-of-the-workflow-admin-console/m-p/237290)

Now I understand the cause of the error: as Axel Faust said, *"..the tables for historic information do require referential integrity in their relation to the process definition and are not automatically cascade-deleted when you undeploy a process."*

Thanks to all for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

put this configuration in application.yml of springboot. basically it couldn't find your .bpmn file. just pointing to the correct location would solve this issue

```
spring:
  activiti:
    database-schema-update: true
    db-history-used: true
    check-process-definitions: true
    process-definition-location-prefix: file:/opt/try-uploads/
    # process-definition-location-prefix: classpath:/processes/
    process-definition-location-suffixes: '*.bpmn, *.bpmn20.xml'
    history-level: audit
```